# Will I have to get a new student visa if I apply for a change in name in my passport?

Tags: passports, study, f1-visas

My name on my passport is XYZ only. XYZ is my first name; there is no last name and my F1 visa FNU (first name unavailable) XYZ (last name). I am planning to apply for a name change in my passport from XYZ to XYZ (first name) ABC (last name).

I will get a new passport after the name change. Would I also have to get a new F1 visa, or the old one will work? I have an affidavit from the court stating that I have changed my name from XYZ to XYZ ABC.

Changed the first name to XYZ and last name to ABC due to privacy concerns.

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule. Many married women for example continue using their passports with their old name and visa after they change their name. Your case is a little different because you are getting a new passport in a different name. As a former F1 student myself and the heavy scrutiny of F1 visas now, my advice will be to get a new visa when you travel outside the country to avoid the real possibility of being refused entry.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [Department of State](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html)  says on it's FAQ.

**Q. I changed my name. Is my U.S. visa with my old name still valid?**

> **A.** If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court
>   ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you
>   have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply
>   for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from
>   the United States.